# Can an underage request Italian citizenship through italian ancestor?

Tags: citizenship, italian-citizens

In my team, we would like to sign a Brasilian player who is 15 yo. We discovered he has Italian grandmothers, so we would like to make him obtain Italian citizenship because it would be easier to obtain instead of a student visa.

I read that it's easier to obtain citizenship staying in Italy for a couple of months than ask for it directly from Brasil (it takes 10 years).

The only doubt is: can he apply for citizenship being underage or should his Italian descent parent do this?

Comment: He might *already* be an Italian citizen from birth, passed down from his grandmother, in which case he wouldn't need to "obtain" Italian citizenship; he would just need to obtain documentation of it. But note that before 1948, Italian citizenship could only be passed from the father, not the mother, so we would need more information about when each generation was born in order to tell.

Comment: His great-grandfather was born in 1888 in Italy, we have birth certificate